# Z and 3z Isomorphism

Tags: group-theory

I was trying to use the isomorphism theorem and I ended up with an example of a restriction from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $3 \mathbb{Z}$ which was confusing.

The kernels $0$ and $\mathbb{Z} / 0$ is supposedly isomorphic to $3 \mathbb{Z}$ when it only has 3 elements. That is counterintuitive to me because there is seemingly no 1 to 1 correspondence.

Comment: $n\Bbb Z$ consists of the integer multiples of $n$. So $|n\Bbb Z|=|\Bbb Z|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3\Bbb Z$ doesn't have $3$ elements, 
$$3\Bbb Z=\{3n|n\in\Bbb Z\}$$
The isomorphism $\phi:\Bbb Z\to 3\Bbb Z$ is $n\mapsto 3n$.