# Hows this restriction an isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

I'm just looking at the restriction of $\mathbb{Z}$ to $3\mathbb{Z}$. There's an isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z} / 0$ viz $n \rightarrow 3n$, but I am confused how that implies the restriction is technically surjective.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What do you mean by $\mathbb Z/0$?  Isn't $\frac a3$ what gets mapped to each $a\in 3\mathbb Z$?

Comment: J.W. Tanner I have primarily been researching the newest developments - ^ _ ^ pre image has to do with fiber bundles to me and that is a new topic so i was probably overlooking it thanks.

Comment: Using the first isomorphism theorem, when there is an isomorphism from a group to another group  that induces an isomorphism from the quotient of the first group by the kernel of the map to the other group. The map i started with is a restriction and the induced map was multiplication by three, are they the same? Thx

Comment: This is not normally called a “restriction”. Where did you encounter that nomenclature? A “restriction” usually refers to a function $f\colon A\to B$, and given a subset of $A$, $C\subseteq A$, the **restriction** of $f$ to $C$ is the map that results form $f$ by restricting the domain.

Comment: follow-up of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3490644/z-and-3z-isomorphism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call the isomorphism that you mentioned $f$. Then, by the 1st isomorphism theorem

$\mathop{Z} / ker f \cong f(\mathop{Z})$

Now note that $ker f =\{0\}$, because the only element that goes to 0 is 0 itself.

Also, the image is $3\mathop{Z}$, because for any $3n \in 3\mathop{Z}$, we have $f(n)=3n$.

Hence, you have

$\mathop{Z} / \{0\} \cong 3\mathop{Z}$.

But, actually $\mathop{Z} / \{0\}$ is just $\mathop{Z}$, because dividing by the trivial group doesn't affect.

So the relation that we get, is just the relation that we started with, namely

$\mathop{Z} \cong 3\mathop{Z}$.

In fact, this is the case if you start with any isomorphism relation $G\cong G'$. In other words, if you apply the 1st isomorphism theorem to an isomorphism relation then you will just go back to the point that you started with.

Comment: And does that mean the map 3n is the same as the restriction? Please + Thanks

Comment: Please see the edited comment, does it answer your question?